# Trigger child component method from parent event

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am very new to VueJS and JavaScript and your help would be much appreciated.

My method "`greet`" is not working and I am unsure why. When I click on the button "change to bar" I get the error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "greet" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

> found in

> ```
> ---> <Chatjsvue> at src\components\vueChartjs\Chatjsvue.vue
>        <App> at src\App.vue
>          <Root>
> ```

**chartjs.vue**

```html
<template src="../../views/chartjshtml/chartsjs.html"></template>
<script>
  import LineChart from '@/assets/javascripts/chartjsline'

    export default {
    components: {
      'line-chart': LineChart 
    }
  }
</script>
```

**chartsjs.html**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
     <ul>
       <li><button v-on:click="greet()">change to bar</button></li>
       <li><line-chart></line-chart></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**chartsjsline.js**

```js
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Line,
  data() {
      return {
         datacollection: {
            //Data to be represented on x-axis
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            datasets: [{
               label: 'Activities ChartJS Line',
               backgroundColor: '#f87979',
               pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
               borderWidth: 1,
               pointBorderColor: '#249EBF',
               //Data to be represented on y-axis
               data: [40, 20, 30, 50, 90, 10, 20, 40, 50, 70, 90, 100]
            }]
         },
         //Chart.js options that controls the appearance of the chart
         options: {
            scales: {
               yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: true
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                     display: true
                  }
               }],
               xAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                     display: false
                  }
               }]
            },
            legend: {
               display: true
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
         },
      }
   },
   methods: {
      greet() {
        alert('hello');
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      //renderChart function renders the chart with the datacollection and options object.
      this.renderChart(this.datacollection, this.options)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `<line-chart>` component (instance of `LineChart`) is a *child* component of your `Chatjsvue` component.

The child methods remain bound to those instances.

However it is extremely easy [from the parent component to access its child component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements), and from there to execute their methods:

1. Keep a reference to your child component, using the [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) special attribute: `<line-chart ref="myLineChart"></line-chart>`
2. Within a parent method, access the referred child using [`this.$refs.myLineChart`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs).
3. Then you have access to everything on this child instance, including its methods: `this.$refs.myLineChart.greet()`

Working example:

```js
Vue.component('chart-js', {
  template: '#chartjs',
  methods: {
    lineChildGreet() {
      // Access the child component through $refs.
      // Then you can execute its methods.
      this.$refs.myLineChart.greet();
    },
  },
});

Vue.component('line-chart', {
  template: '#lineChart',
  methods: {
    greet() {
      alert('hello');
    },
  },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <chart-js></chart-js>
</div>

<template id="chartjs">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
     <ul>
       <li><button v-on:click="lineChildGreet">greet on child component</button></li>
       <!-- Keep a REFerence to the child component -->
       <li><line-chart ref="myLineChart"></line-chart></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="lineChart">
  <span>LineChart</span>
</template>
```

Comment: What if I have `<span @click="handleClick">LineChart</span>`? How can I trigger click event on root element of the component template from 'chart-js' component?

Comment: @webprogrammer you should make it a new question with specific details of your issue, instead of commenting an old post which is different from what you say you try to achieve.

Comment: ghybs, ok, thank you! But I have already found the solution. I thought my question is related to your answer. Sorry to have disturbed you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the greet() method to the chartjs.vue component, instead of chartsjsline.

Comment: thank you. I thought the methods could be called via the chartjsline.js file as i had this in the .vue file as `import LineChart from '@/assets/javascripts/chartjsline'` but i guess that does not work - i have now called the method in the .vue file - thank you